# AVAudioPlayer works fine on iPhone, but doesn't play on iPad?

Tags: iphone, ipad, avfoundation

Greetings,

I have an app were the sounds play find on iPhone but on iPad..no sound at all.

Here's a code snippet:

```
self.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath] error:nil];
[self.player play];
```

Any hints as to why no sound on iPad?
Other apps on the same iPad play sounds fine.
And/or ways to track down the error?

Answer (score 2):

O.k. My mistake.
I have 4.2 on my iPad, where the orientation switch now is the mute switch.
However, the iPod application doesn't obey the mute switch.

Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure that the NSURL method call returns a non-nil result?

Comment: Hmm. Same .ipa file on an iphone 3g, or 4 works fine. Install on iPad. No sound.  I'll put some checks in to dump to log the NSURL return value later and report back.

Comment: My problem AVAudioPlayer works fine on iPad, but doesn't play on iPhone?How can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem while I was deploying to ios 3.x.

### iPhone 4 & iPad

worked fine with my .wav file

### iTouch

didn't worked at all through my ear phone

### Here is good way to check and fix your problem

1) Check the file location. (NSURL)

2) Convert into Apple's recommend '.caf' sound format.

Finder->Type 'Terminal'-> Inside terminal Go to the where .wav file locate->Type 'afconvert -f caff -d LEI16@11025 inputfile.wav outfile.caf

3) Maybe you didn't import AudioToolBox framework library.